# How do i add spaces to my censor?

Tags: java, string

Im trying to produce spaces in between my words like "x xx xxx" but instead i get "xxxxxx" whenever i type out something like "1 12 123" in the interaction. can someone tell me what im missing?

```
public class Censor{

  public String block(String s, char c){
    if (s.length() == 0) {
      return "";
    }
    else {
      return c + block(s.substring(1), c);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Show us sample input and expected output

Comment: input: new Censor().block("example here ok", 'x')

Comment: exected output: xxxxxxx xxxx xx 
but instead i keep getting xxxxxxxxxxxxx without the spaces

Comment: @AppleMuffin -  can't you use `String.replaceAll()`?

Comment: You need to modify your return statement in else block as return c+" "+block(s.substring(1), c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one substitution rule: replace first character with `c`. If you want spaces to be kept as spaces, you'll need another substitution rule, as such:

```
public String block(String s, char c){
    if (s.length() == 0)
      return "";
    if (s.charAt(0) == ' ')
        return " " + block(s.substring(1), c);
     return c + block(s.substring(1), c);
}
```

---

By the way, a recursion that scans the entire string might not be the best way to do this (unless you have a different agenda than meets the eye). I would suggest using a regular expression, for example:

```
s.replaceAll("[^\\s]", "x")
```

would replace all non-whitespace characters with `x`.